# Is there any way to crop a blob or a base 64 string image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I basically have a chess board and a piece bank beside it on a webpage. I capture these elements with the code below and save an image in a base 64 string. Is there any way I can crop the image so that only the board is in the picture?

```
const blobToBase64 = async (blob) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
      }

    const saveImg = () => {
        domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('main'))
            .then(async function(blob) {
        await blobToBase64(blob)
            .then(base64String => setPostData({...postData, image: base64String}));
    });
    }
```

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from './actions/posts'

import Pieces from './components/Pieces';
import Board from './components/Board';
import Gallery from './components/gallery/Gallery'
import Form from './components/form/form';

const App = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return(
        <>
            <ul className='header'>
                <div className='header-text' variant='h1' align='center'>Chess Position Gallery</div>
            </ul>
            <div className='main' id='main'>
                <div className='main' id='piecesAndBoard'>
                    <Pieces />

                    <Board />
                </div>

                <Form />

            </div>
            <Gallery />
        </>
            
    );
}
export default App;
```

This is what it looks like now: [image: pic]

Also the pieces don't seem to be lining up correctly in the piece bank on the left, what could be causing that?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you capture just the board? To the second question: Maybe a bug in `domtoimage`?

Comment: @xehpuk If I capture just the board then the pieces won't show up so I need to capture both of them. Do you have a suggestion to get around that?